# How to find C functions without a prototype?

Tags: c, function-prototypes

Company policy dictates that every function in C source code has a prototype. I inherited a project with its own make system (so I **cannot** test it on gcc or Visual Studio) and found that one of the files has some static functions declared without prototypes. Is there a way (not necessarily with a compiler) to list all functions without prototypes in all .c files?

Comment: static functions don't really need prototypes, unless they are called before they are defined

Comment: @Paul: Yes, but I suppose it allows the project manager to quickly see what functions are available etc.

Comment: If you can't use another compiler, for reasons unknown, you'll have to get a separate static analyser tool. All such tools in the market will find all missing prototypes for you

Comment: `its own make system` - what do you mean?

Comment: @fableal: They have their own compiler which is not gcc, that is run under make.

Comment: Then I guess the solution from @Lundin applies; unless that compiler has an option to detect missing prototypes like gcc has

Comment: @PaulR: A prototype can be either standalone: `void foo(void);` or part of a definition: `void foo(void) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: @Gnubie: This is more of a discussion for the Programming SX, but I think it is a mistake for a policy like that to apply retroactively to an old code base.  Modifying old (working) code just to meet a new standard is likely to introduce bugs.  You should apply the policy to new code, and update code that you directly touch, but leave the rest of the code base alone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gcc has an option to warn you about this:

```
gcc -Wmissing-prototypes
```

You can turn this warning into an error to stop compilation and force people to fix it:

```
gcc -Werror=missing-prototypes
```

If you just want to list it you can compile with the `gcc` option `-Wmissing-prototypes` and grep for **no previous prototype for** in the log.

**Update based on edit**:

Since you now mention that you can't use gcc, you'll have to find a similar option for your current compiler. Most compilers have such an option. Start with the man page or the built in help output.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but it has its own build system, so I can't test it on gcc.

Comment: "build system" != "compiler". I would presume that whatever compiler this custom build system uses (gcc/icc/clang/.......) has various options/switches to enable warnings/errors/etc. That would be the place to start, even if it's not gcc...

Answer (score 5):

`ctags` can do that!

`--c-kinds=p` generates the list of all function prototypes

`--c-kinds=f` generates the list of all function definitions

Now you just need to compare those.

`diff -u <(ctags -R -x --sort=yes --c-kinds=f | cut -d' ' -f1) <(ctags -R -x --sort=yes --c-kinds=p | cut -d' ' -f1) | sed -n 's/^-//p'`