# can the following C macro cause problems?

Tags: c, macros

I would like to create two macros. One of them will expand to function prototype and function content and the other one will expand to only function prototype. I'm thinking to create followings:

```
#ifdef SOME_CONDITION
#define MY_MACRO(prototype, content) prototype;
#else
#define MY_MACRO(prototype, content) prototype content
#endif
```

As an example usage

```
MY_MACRO(int foo(int a, int b)
,
{
     return a + b;
}
)
```

These macros seems working fine. Do you think are those macros safe enough so that they will work for every kind of C code as intended? Or do you see any pitfall?

Comment: Why are you doing this way? I suspect that second My_MACRO will work.

Comment: In which case will you want this expansion: `#define MY_MACRO(prototype, content) prototype, content`

Comment: What's the purpose of this ?

Comment: Let me try to explain why I need this. I need this to be able write unit tests. Say, I have two modules A and B. A module depends on B. I want to unit test A. B has a header file that has an inline function. Inline function has the definition (content) in the header file. Module A calls that function. While unit testing module A, I need to be able to create mock version of inline function in module B header. But since it has the implementation in header file, I cannot create a mock version of that function. That's why I need macros similar to ones in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did something similar quite recently and learned the pitfalls of passing in code as a macro argument.

For example try this seemingly correct code (using the first macro definition):

```
MY_MACRO(int foo(int a, int b)
,
{
    int c = 1, d = 2;
    return a + b + c + d;
}
)
```

You'll most likely see a compile error something to the tune of the macro expecting only 2 arguments while you provided 3.

What happens is that the macros are compiled by the pre-processor which doesn't care about C syntax.  So in it's eyes, each `,` is a argument separator.  So it thinks that the first argument to the macro is `int foo(int a, int b)`, the second argument `{ int c = 1` and the third argument as `d = 2; return a + b + c + d; }`.

So basically, the moral of the story is that "never pass in code as argument".  Most macros that want to be flexible code-wise compile down into a `if` or a `for` statement (e.g. `list_for_each` in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h#L407).

I'd suggest that you stick to standard `#ifdef`ery in your situation. e.g.

```
#ifndef UNIT_TEST

int foo(...) {
   //actual implementation
}

#else

int foo(..) {
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

This sort of code is fairly standard: http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v3.13/include/linux/of.h  (search for `CONFIG_OF`)

Answer (score 4):

The first major pitfall, it doesn't work. When the second macro is used, it creates

```
int foo(int a, int b), { return a + b; }
```

which is not a valid function definition. To fix this, you must remove the `,` in the macro definition.

The second pitfall I see, usually C programmers don't use such fancy macros. It's simply confusing, when you're used to reading C source code.

If you're worried about diverging prototype declarations and corresponding function definitions, I suggest using appropriate compiler flags or tools. See this question and answers, [How to find C functions without a prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15974112/1741542)

Comment: Yes, this wouldn't work. I've corrected the question. I made the mistake while I was transforming original source code.

Comment: If you really want to do this, a [variadic macro](http://stackoverflow.com/q/679979/1741542) or http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html, like in Jens Gustedt 's answer, might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of pitfalls, it is simply too naive, I think.

1. never have macros that change the grammatical parsing, here in particular that add a `;` at the end. Nobody will be able to comprehend code like that that has function-like macros invocations in file scope without a terminating semicolon.
2. your macro expects two arguments, exactly. If your code block in the second argument contains an unprotected `,` operator, you are screwed.
3. Your second variant should definitively not have a `,` on the right hand side.

This would work a bit better

```
#ifdef SOME_CONDITION
#define MY_MACRO(prototype, ...) prototype
#else
#define MY_MACRO(prototype, ...) prototype __VA_ARGS__ extern double dummyForMY_MACRO[]
#endif
```

you'd have to use that as

```
MY_MACRO(int foo(int a, int b), { return a + b; });
```

So this provides at least something visually more close to C code (well...) and handles the problem of the intermediate commas. The unused variable `dummyForMY_MACRO` should cause no harm, but "eats" the `;` in the second form.

Not that I'd suggest that you use such a thing untested like this.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think are those macros safe enough so that they will work for every kind of C code as intended? Or do you see any pitfall?

Do not attempt to re-invent the C language. The people who read your code will be other C programmers. You can expect them to know C. You cannot expect them to know "the-home-brewed-garage-hacker-macro-language".

Strive to write code that is as simple as readable as possible. Avoid complexity, avoid confusion. Don't attempt to create solutions when there exists no problem to solve.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to solve unit testing problem that I explained in the comment of the question.

Comment: @user3472693 So the problem you are trying to solve is "I can't create a function". This seems like an artificial problem. Why not? Why would it matter if it is inline or not? Writing obscure macros is most often not a good solution to anything. If the unit test is buggier than the code to be tested, it is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Find below example which helps you to fulfils both of your requirements:

```
#ifdef SOME_CONDITION
   #define MY_MACRO(a, b) \
   int foo(int a, int b);
#else
   #define MY_MACRO(a, b) \
   int foo(int a, int b) \
   {\
      return 0;\
   }
#endif
```

You can use 1st macro by **MY_MACRO(a, b)** and 2nd macro as **MY_MACRO(a, b);**